# Can I use DIV class and ID together in CSS?

Tags: css, html

Can I use DIV Class and ID together in CSS?
For example:

```
<div class="x" id="y">
    --
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you forgot to use the `code markdown`.

Comment: Your HTML there is fine. You can specify a `class` and an `id` on the same element.

Comment: Did you mean "How can I use a class and ID together?" ?

Comment: @Billa, it might be worth having a read of the [SO Mark-down editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for help using the Mark-down editor.

Comment: of course you can, you can even specify more than one class for each element (i.e.: `<div class="x z b">`). what you cannot do is to use more than one id per element (i.e. `<div id="y w">`)

Comment: Thanks everyone for such a quick answers :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.

```
#y.x {
 /* will select element of id="y" that also has class="x" */
}
```

Similarly:

```
.x#y {
 /* will select elements of class="x" that also have an id="y" */
}
```

Incidentally this might be useful in some use cases (wherein classes are used to represent some form of event or interaction), but for the most part it's not *necessarily* that useful, since `id`s are unique in the document anyway. But if you're using classes for user-interaction then it *can* be useful to know.

Comment: Not positive this is the case, but I remember something about putting the ID first not working in IE6 (I know, it's old, but thought I'd mention this, just in case).

Comment: @Matthewpavkov, ...gosh, it's been a while since I had to consider IE6 (or, indeed, IE7; yay hobbyist web-dev!), but I take your point. It could be important. +1, sir! =)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use as many classes as needed on a tag, but an id must be unique to the document.
Also be careful of using too many divs, when another more semantic tag can do the job.

```
<p id="unique" class="x y z">Styled paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can.

Your HTML there is just fine. To style the elements with css you can use the following approaches:

```
#y {
    ...
}

.x {
    ...
}

#y.x {
    ...
}
```

Also you can add as many classes as you wish to your element

```
<div id="id" class="classA classB classC ...">
</div>
```

And you can style that element using a selector with any combination of the classes and id. 
For example:

```
#id.classA.classB.classC {
     ...
}

#id.classC {
}
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: This is a direct answer to the question. Simple question - simple answer. This is a 2 years old post btw.

Comment: The age of the post does not influence its quality. It looks much better now :) +1

Answer (score 4):

That's HTML, but yes, you can bang pretty much any selectors you like together.

```
#x.y { }
```

(And the HTML is fine too)

Comment: And a selector for the DIV (not class) and ID: `div.y {...}` although it sounds somewhat dubious to change the *type* of an element referenced with a given `id`, so... not sure if question was a typo or what :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target a specific class *and* ID in CSS, then use a format like `div.x#y {}`.

Answer (score 1):

#y.x should work. And it's convenient too. You can make a page with different kinds of output. You can give a certain element an id, but give it different classes depending on the look you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You just need to understand what they are for, the `class` is more general and can be used several times, the `id` (is like your id's) you can use it only once.

This excellent tutorial  helped me with that:

[The Difference Between ID and Class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Though it's not an exact answer to your question I'm sure it will help you a lot!

Good luck!

EDIT: Reading your question, I just want to clarify that:

```
<div class="x" id="y">
    --
</div>
```

And that if you want to "use them" in CSS for styling purposes you should do as [David Says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371733/can-i-use-div-class-and-id-together-in-css/4371743#4371743): `#x.y { }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in one single division you can use both but it's not very common. While styling you will call both so it will cause some ambiguity if you don't properly choose "x" and "y".
Use `#` for ID and `.` for class. And for overall division you will either do separate styling or write:  `#x .y` for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not? Then CSS that applies to class "x" AND CSS that applies to ID "y" applies to the div.