# HTML CSS Buttons Hover Wont Work Through Class

Tags: html, css, class, button, hover

I don't understand why does this work :

```
.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top: 2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

But this wont work :

```
.button:hover { 
    font-size:17px;
}
```

It works when I use id but I want it to activate for all buttons :

```
#btnhome:hover{
    font-size:17px;
}
```

This works fine but with class it wont? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Please include a full test-case over on http://jsfiddle.net showing what doesn't work for you exactly.

Comment: Maybe your CSS-rules rewrite later? Show you CSS.

Comment: @Belyash I don't understand because this is the only :hover style I'm using in my whole CSS. Nothing should be overiding it. What do you mean by "css rules rewrite later"?

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm in Chrome and this seems to be working fine.

Comment: @jkinz Something in my CSS is overiding it I think..Can't find out what though...

Comment: @user1880779 Do you happen to have a hosted version somewhere?

Comment: @jkinz Yes, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/3/), when you remove the '!important', hover doesn't work anymore. I want to find out what is overiding it without the '!important' so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `id` and it works so sure something has to do with the specificity, over riding, try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yAU22/)

[**Demo + !important**](http://jsfiddle.net/yAU22/)

```
.button:hover { 
    font-size:17px !important; /* Actually you don't even need !important */
}
```

Comment: Yes it works now (only with !important). What could be over riding it I don't understand? Can you maybe explain? Where can I find the over-rider? :)

Comment: @user1880779 I can't unless and until I see your CSS, paste it in a fiddle and share a link :)

Comment: Can't you just blind shoot? :) What could it be? Something obvious?

Comment: blind shoot lol no...but I can you tell something like `div.container ul li input[type=button].button:hover` is much more specific than `.button:hover`

Comment: Don't use ID for add style! Use `class`.

Comment: @Belyash I need to use both because I have 4 buttons and I have styles that apply to all of them and some styles are different for each so I just use class for same styles and if some are different i add id too.

Comment: We could certainly blind shoot but it'd probably be more useful for you to fire up FireBug in Firefox or DevTools in Chrome and have it show you exactly what's over-riding it for you.

Comment: @Belyash seriously? Any reason?

Comment: Note that IDs are more specific than classes, so your 'just add ID too' might work for you, but note that there are drawbacks (namely your style declaration with an ID is likely going to over-ride subsequent styles just using classes.

Comment: Final thought: If you find yourself using `!important` more than a few times, it's a sign that your CSS selectors have gotten a bit too specific in general. Might be time to step back and rethink a few things

Comment: @DA This would be my first !important, I didn't even know about it before.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Would only CSS file without html be enough for you to see an answer?

Comment: It works only because I gave it !important tag, without it, doesn't work.

Comment: @user1880779 Got it, you are using ID and a class together, `id` is more specific than class..learn specificity http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/14/

Comment: I don't get it? But I need to use them both for properties that are the same and for the ones that are different/specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371733/can-i-use-div-class-and-id-together-in-css You removed the id for btncontact and now its working only on contact button im confused.

Comment: @user1880779 is just the specificity issue, see check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/16/ `#btnhome:hover, #btnabout:hover, #btncontact:hover {
    font-size:17px;
}`

Comment: So basically you think this is the only way to fix it? If so, ok.

Comment: @user1880779 ya it's completely fine, you are not using any hacks

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    `.button *:hover { font-size:17px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there is an external .css file included by you via using **link** tag, in which `.button:hover {font-size:somethingelse !important;}` is defined. That's why you can't change it unless using !important again.

Comment: Yes there is only one .css file included 
'<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />'
But this is the one in which im defining it all and it doesn't have that line you posted...? The only !important tag is the one I just added so it would work.

Comment: Then is there any code like button:hover{font-size:somethingelse;} defined after your new css code, because all the css selector before your new css selector will be overriden by the new selector.

Comment: I don't understand because this is the only :hover style I'm using in my whole CSS. Nothing should be overiding it.

Comment: Or is there any internal style sheet defined? If yes, please check, because :hover can't be defined via using inline style.

Comment: No, I don't have any internal style sheet defined. This is the only style sheet I have and the only one I'm using/defining. I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is specificity. The ID is taking precedent over the pseudo style. You need to either re-write the CSS to be more general, and only put the unique values on the IDs or use the IDs plus the pseudo selector.

I took the common stuff from the ID's and moved them to a base .button class:

```
.button{
    width: 84px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color:#000;
    border: none;
    color: white;    
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
}
.button:hover { 
     font-size:17px;
}
```

Check out this fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/kJfmR/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing the same problem:

I had one similar to the above, my code was like this:

```
<style>


.btto:hover{
   background-color: grey ;
   cursor: pointer;}
</style>

<body>

<button class="btto" style="color:white; 
            background-color:black;
            padding:4%;
            width:50%;
            border:none"> Buy Tickets </button>
</body>
```

I think background-color of button inside body was overriding the one inside style
so what i did was:

```
<style>

.btto{
        color:white; 
        background-color:black;
        padding:4%;
        width:50%;
        border:none;
    }
 .btto:hover{
   background-color: grey ;
   cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>

<body>

<button class="btto">Buy Tickets</button> 

</body>
```