# DIV does not get styles from CSS class when being styled with id

Tags: html, css, class

The below code does not work, perhaps because I am using `class` and `id` in the same div.  I know they are supposed to work.

Reference: [Can I use DIV class and ID together in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371733/can-i-use-div-class-and-id-together-in-css)

```css
.PB {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 201px;
  height: 422px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#pb1-1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 65px;
  height: 98.5px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
#pb1-2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 65px;
  height: 98.5px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 68px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
#pb1-3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 65px;
  height: 98.5px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 136px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
.pu:hover {
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="PB">
  <div id="pb1-1" class="pu">1&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="pb1-2" class="pu">2&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="pb1-3" class="pu">3&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm not sure if hyphen are legal. Did you try pb11 instead of pb1-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overwrite your `:hover` CSS rules using **`!important`**, because `id`'s are always given more preference than classes. Like:

```
.pu:hover {
    font-size:24px !important;
    background-color:#999999 !important;
}
```

Have a look at the updated snippet below:

```css
.PB {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#000;
  width:201px;
  height:422px;
  z-index: 1; 
}

#pb1-1 {position:absolute; margin:0px; background-color:green; width:65px; height:98.5px; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; z-index:2; text-align:right; font-size:14px; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;}

#pb1-2 {position:absolute; margin:0px; background-color:yellow; width:65px; height:98.5px; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:68px; z-index:2; text-align:right; font-size:14px; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;}
#pb1-3 {position:absolute; margin:0px; background-color:red; width:65px; height:98.5px; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:136px; z-index:2; text-align:right; font-size:14px; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;}

.pu:hover {
  font-size:24px!important;
  background-color:#999999!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="PB">
  <div id="pb1-1" class="pu">1&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="pb1-2" class="pu">2&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="pb1-3" class="pu">3&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Chiwda Just try to use common styling in single class no need write that in separate id's.

Comment: Its my pleasure @Chiwda

Answer (score 1):

This is because style of your ID's are overriding class styles (including with hover effect).

More information about cascading order can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

In your example, I would avoid using `!important`, and use only classes to define styles:

```css
.PB {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 201px;
    height: 422px;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.pu {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 98.5px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.pb1-1 { background-color: green; left: 0; }
.pb1-2 { background-color: yellow; left: 68px; }
.pb1-3 { background-color: red; left: 136px; }

.pu:hover {
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="PB">
    <div class="pu pb1-1">1&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pu pb1-2">2&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pu pb1-3">3&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, the width, height etc. change in later pb1-* divs, so I can't put them in a class.  I just showed the first three for simplicity and they happened to be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with pseudo classes

```
.PB {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 201px;
    height: 422px;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.pu {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 98.5px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.pu:nth-child(1) { background-color: green; left: 0; }
.pu:nth-child(2) { background-color: yellow; left: 68px; }
.pu:nth-child(3) { background-color: red; left: 136px; }

.pu:hover {
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #999999;
}

<div class="PB">
    <div class="pu">1&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pu">2&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pu">3&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qy5jzha4/2/)!

Answer (score -1):

Add `<style type="text/css">` attribute. That's your problem. It will work.